# Node.js Custom Middleware Using An Object Of Functions

Tags: node.js, express

In Express.js, ihave been having problems with making my own middleware. I know that middleware is supposed to be a function, but can the middleware function be inside an array.
For Example:

module.js:

```
module.exports = {
  function1: function(req, res) {
    console.log('function1'); 
    //second edit.
    I want to return something as well
    return 'hello world';
    //if i add next(); it wont call the next();
  },
  function2: function(req, res) {
     console.log('function2');
  }
}
```

app.js:

```
const express = require('express')
, middleware = require('./module')
, app = express();

app.use(middleware.function1);
app.use(middleware.function2);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  //this is an edit: i want to use some code here like
  res.send('Hello World');
  middleware.function1();
});

app.listen(8080);
```

When i Do This, the webpage just doesn't load. Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing crucial part **next** function  (which is callback to trigger next middleware in the sequence) in defining middleware functions function1 and function2.

Have you seen https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html ?

In below code, you are not passing req, res to the middleware function.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  middleware.function1();
});
```

OR call it directly as below

```
app.get('/', middleware.function1);
```

Comment: I want to have some code that i want to use before i call the middleware, is there any way to do that?

Comment: It will work just like middleware. Just call it before the other middlewares.

Comment: I dont understand, i have added an edit to help you understand my problem more. Thanks!

Comment: You call them in sequence like app.get('/', middleware.function1, middleware.function2); where function1 can be what you want to call before other middleware

Comment: Unless you first correct the problems I already mentioned like adding next function, it won't work. After that you can add the pieces you want and it will work.

Comment: ok i have made more edits, if you can see them i would much appreciate it. Thank You So Much!

Comment: middleware functions are special functions where you cannot call return because it breaks the flow of express evented loop. You can pass on data instead by adding attributes to "res" which can be used subsequently in next middlewares.